# Deploying .Net Windows Applications that depends on ODP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have an application (.net 3.5 app) that depends on odp.net (11g). I had installed the odp.net on the production machine, i deployed my binaries. The program works fine, however it displays an error like this:

This application has failed to start because MSVCR71.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix the problem.

The machine has Windows 2003 R2 as OS. This error occurs on the catch Oracle Exception block of my code. The program is supposed to display a message box indicating the error. It works as expected in my development machine... Could you help me in how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem figured out, without installing the Visual C run time... Instead of using the XCopy installation, i used the ODP.NET Installer... Works fine now...

Answer (score 1):

I think  this is a microsoft visual C runtime V. 7.1 dll.  Is the microsoft visual C runtime V. 7.1 installed on the machine?

[this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326922) may help

Comment: Oh i c... most likely it's not installed... but from what i've known i don't remember referencing this dll in my apps

Comment: probably the ODP.net is referencing it, maybe try reinstalling that? Does the dll exist on your machine?  everything (http://www.voidtools.com/download.php) is a good way to find out quickly

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice... is there an installer for this library? I install the Visual C++ 2008 runtime, but it still displays the same error